# What is the purpose of the Notes parameter in the SPRoleAssignment constructor?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, roles, spprincipal

There are two constructors for the `SPRoleAssignment` class:

```
public SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal principal)
public SPRoleAssignment(string LoginName, string Email, string Name, string Notes)
```

The definition of the `Notes` parameter is following (from MSDN):

> The notes for the user.

In Visual Studio (2013), IntelliSense gives me following definition:

> ***Notes:*** String that contains notes for the user.

But nowhere I can find more information regarding the purpose of this parameter. After initializing the class, I cannot find a property *Notes* on the object. Then I thought it might be in the *Member* property of the object, since the parameters *LoginName* and *Name* are properties of the `SPPrincipal` class. But also there, nothing about a *Notes* property.

I went looking on MSDN and several questions here on SharePoint.SE or StackOverflow but everywhere the parameter is just filled in with `"Notes"`.

Hence my question: what is the purpose of this parameter? And how can I get the value after initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigating I found that *Notes* is a property of the `SPUser` class. Thus, following would work:

```
var spRole = new SPRoleAssignment("domain\\name", "abc@xyz.com", "name", "notes for user");
var spUser = (SPUser)spRole.Member;
var notes = spUser.Notes;
```